# Change ddev password for a single project

Tags: mysql, docker, ddev

I try to change a ddev database password for a single project.

I need to check sign-escaping for a project, because I want to know how and if that works.

How can I change a database password in a single ddev-project?

I use

- Docker 3.5.1 (66090)
- ddev 1.17.2
- macOS Catalina 10.15.7

I got answers in slack, thanks for that, but I run into those errors, if I do so:

```
ddev mysql

MariaDB [db]> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'db'@'%';
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'db'@'localhost' (using password: YES)


MariaDB [db]> ALTER USER 'db'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'test/test:test@test?test#test&test"';
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation
MariaDB [db]> ALTER USER 'db'@'db' IDENTIFIED BY 'test/test:test@test?test#test&test"';
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation
```

Comment: Since you asked this and got an answer in Slack, please write up the answer yourself, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your answers, if I find a working way, I will do so.

Comment: As answered in slack, you need to `ddev mysql -uroot -proot` to have privileges.